# Fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic surface is Gromov hyperbolic

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Does anyone have a reference for the proof of the result in the title?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you would write a somewhat less terse version of the question you  might get a better reception. You can still [edit] the question.

Comment: This question is not research-level - any introductory text will contain a proof of this fact.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, let $X$ be a $n$-dimensional closed hyperbolic manifold and let $G$ denote its fundamental group. It is a standard theorem in Riemannian geometry that the universal cover of such a manifold is isometric to the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. Therefore, $G$ acts geometrically on $\mathbb{H}^n$ and we deduce from Milnor-Svarc lemma that $G$ and $\mathbb{H}^n$ are quasi-isometric. Of course, $\mathbb{H}^n$ is Gromov-hyperbolic and we conclude that $G$ so is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the reference is Jim Cannon's article in Bedford, Keane, Series

```
@book{bedford1991ergodic,
  title={Ergodic theory, symbolic dynamics, and hyperbolic spaces},
  author={Bedford, Tim and Michael (Michael S.) Keane and Series, Caroline},
  year={1991},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```